# Bold, Upright and Beautiful epsilon

Tags: math-mode, greek

I was searching for upright, bold, and beautiful epsilon (or other) in math mode as shown here, but can't find it. I can do the right hand side of equation using \symbf but when used it with epsilon, it didn't work.
How do I get that?

[image: Bold epsilon]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also can use a font which has upright greek letters (‘French style’) such as `fourier`. Here is a code, with some improvements as to the spacing:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} 
\usepackage[upright]{fourier}

\begin{document}

\[ \underbrace{\overline{\boldsymbol{\varepsilon}}_k}_{\mathclap{\substack{\text{constant}\\ \text{in } \Omega^s_k}}} = \frac{1}{V^s_k}\int_{\Omega^s_k}\mathbf{L}_d \mathbf{u}^h(\mathbf{x})\,\mathrm{d}\Omega \]%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It works if I run with a new file opened. When I used it with my current latex, Elsevier template, an error "\hbar is already defined". Please help again.
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{mathtools} 
\usepackage[upright]{fourier}

Comment: If you load `fourier`, you shouldn't load `amsfonts` nor `amssymb` – I guess it's the reason of the message.

Comment: I removed amsfonts and amssymb as suggested, I still can't run your code within equation environment.

Comment: Maybe there's something in the Elsevier template. Could you post a minimal,  yet complete, code reproducing the problem?

Comment: Sorry for my dumb. Your advice works properly. I just need to remove some packages like bm and upgreek. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

In LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX with `unicode-math`, you can use `\symup{\varepsilon}` or `\mbfvarepsilon`.  [Here is a comparison of this and other symbols in a half-dozen different fonts.](https://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/fonts/newcomputermodern/doc/newcm-unimath-symbols.pdf)

In PDFLaTeX, you must load a math font that comes in bold upright, such as Euler or Math Design Utopia, Garamond or Charter, and optionally `bm` for bold math.  You might do this through `isomath` for convenience. This allows you to write `\mathbf{\varepsilon}` or `\boldsymbol{\mathrm{\varepsilon}}`.

Here is a MWE for Math Design Utopia in PDFLaTeX:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[utopia]{mathdesign}
\usepackage[rmdefault=mdput,
            OMLmathrm,
            OMLmathbf         
           ]{isomath}

\begin{document}
\[\varepsilon \quad \mathrm{\varepsilon} \quad  \mathbf{\varepsilon} \quad \boldsymbol{\mathrm{\varepsilon}}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: MathDesign Utopia sample]

Use `mdput` with Math Design Utopia, `mdbch` with Math Design Charter and `mdugm` with Math Design Garamond.

The equivalent in LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX is to load the `fourier-otf` package and use `\symbfup{\varepsilon}` or `\mbfvarepsilon`.  You could also set up `unicode-math` to treat `\mathbf` as a synonym for `\symbfup`, for backward-compatibility with code such as the above.